# Unable to generate system core dump after setting "ulimit -c unlimited"

Tags: java, jvm, redhat, coredump

I'm running on: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)

Error:  Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

After setting the core file size to unlimited, and confirming the settings with:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 773690
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 65536
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I am still unable to have the JVM crash create the system core dump... Any ideas on what may be preventing this?

One thing that should be noted,  if I write a little C++ program which intentionally causes a segmentation fault, then the coredump file is generated immediately:

```
#include <signal.h>

int main() {
  raise (SIGSEGV);
}




$ ./crash
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Produces:

core.43969
```

Comment: to confirm the java process that is running has an unlimited corefile size you need to check the process - it may not have inherited the ulimit command depending on the way the java process is started.

```$ cat /proc/19432/limits |grep -E "Limit|core file size"
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes```

Comment: Thanks ceeaspb, this is exactly what the problem was.  The soft limit was still set to 0, because this program was being launched by another program, which was launched many months ago, and still had the old soft core limit = 0.  So the new program was inheriting the soft core limit = 0 from the old-running program.  Once I restarted the launcher,  it properly generated the core file.